# MDX Covariance per location

Tags: mdx, covariance

I'm trying to see how useful the Covariance function is in MDX. I have two measures, GP and order age. I'd like to compare the correlation between these two variables for every sales location. My current query returns the same value for all locations:

```
with
member [Measures].[r] as correlation( [Location].[Location Name].[Location Name].members, [Measures].[Order Age], [measures].[gp])

select [Measures].[r] on 0,
[Location].[Location Name].[Location Name].members on 1
from [DM OIP]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MDX is calculating the covariance of those two measures across all locations for every row. How about calculating the covariance of those two measures across months for the current location (the location on that row)?

```
with
member [Measures].[r] as correlation( [Date].[Month].[Month].members, [Measures].[Order Age], [measures].[gp])

select [Measures].[r] on 0,
[Location].[Location Name].[Location Name].members on 1
from [DM OIP]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a relationship.

So location is not related to one, or both of the measures used.